Gatling + Graphite trace output to identify errors
How can I see the reason why Gatling doesn't sending metrics into Influx via Graphite?
Is it possible to print detailed log into console?

Add into logback.xml:
<logger name="io.gatling.graphite.sender.TcpSender" level="TRACE" />

